# struct pointer casting and its memory allocation

Tags: c

The point here is the code `int header = (((int)(txUserPtr) - 4))` Illustration of UserTypes and struct pointer casting is great of help! How should I set incoming pointer `txUserPtr` so that `Fun()` would skip following lines. I don't want to execute `error()`.

```
typedef union UserTypes
{
    SAUser           AUser;
    BUser            BUser;
    SCUser           CUser;
    SDUser           DUser;
} UserTypes;

typedef struct AUser
{
    int              userId;
    int              dbIndex;
    ChannelType      ChanType;
 } AUser;
typedef struct AUser
{
    int              userId;
    int              dbIndex;
    ChannelType      ChanType;
 } AUser;

typedef struct BUser
{
    int              userId;
    int              dbIndex;
    ChannelType      ChanType;
 } BUser;

typedef struct CUser
{
    int              userId;
    int              dbIndex;
    ChannelType      ChanType;
 } CUser;

typedef struct DUser
{
    int              userId;
    int              dbIndex;
    ChannelType      ChanType;
 } DUser;

//this is the function I want to test

void Fun(UserTypes * txUserPtr)
{

   int header = (*((int*)(txUserPtr) - 4));

   //the problem is here
   //how should i set incoming pointer "txUserPtr" so that 
   //Fun() would skip following lines.
   // I don't want to execute error()

        if((header & 0xFF000000) != (int)0xAA000000)
        {
            error("sth error\n");
        }
   /*the following is the rest */ 
}
```

Comment: It appears the structs inside the union are all prefixed by an int designating the actual type. This is not very clean: the -4 should actually be "typeof(int)", and the code also presumes that the alignment requirements for the union/structs will all be sizeof int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is relying on undefined behavior, as well as various implementation-defined behavior. Somewhere in your code there should be a struct looking similar to

```
typedef struct 
{
  unsigned int header;
  UserTypes user;
} AHeaderPlusUserTypes;
```

Once you have located that struct, fix the code:

```
void Fun (AHeaderPlusUserTypes* txUserPtr)
{
  if((txUserPtr->header & 0xFF000000u) != 0xAA000000u)
  {
    error("sth error\n");
  }
  /*the following is the rest */ 
}
```

Comment: thanks！ I am doing unit test. I have to set the  incoming parameter to appropriate value so that testing function can cover every branch!

Comment: typedef struct 
{
  unsigned int header[4];
  UserTypes user;
} AHeaderPlusUserTypes;

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand the question.

You wish to avoid the pointer having a certain bit-pattern in its most signficant bits, but it's not clear if the pointer is still expected to somehow contain the address of something you can access in the removed code.

More information about your platform's exact memory map would be necessary in order to solve this, I think.

Answer (score 0):

How about this code?

```
void Fun (int header, UserTypes* txUserPtr)
{
  // exactly safe code
  if ( header & 0xFF000000u) != 0xAA000000u ) {
    error("sth error\n");
  }
  /*the following is the rest */ 
}
```